# Symfony validator exhausting the memory for long running process

Tags: php, symfony, validation, dto, symfony5

I have a process where I try to import a big data to the database.

I'm handling this using a row-by-row approach so I can make the validation for each row.

For some reason, the code starts to run out of memory while running, so I could find the actual part which is causing the memory issue. It was the validator part.

I'm measuring the memory usage for each loop with `memory_get_usage()` function.

This is my code part **main.php**:

```php
foreach ($file as $key => $row) {
    $rowDto = new CsvRowDto($row);
    $rowViolations = $this->csvRowValidator->isValid($rowDto);
}
```

And the **CsvRowValidator.php**:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace whatever\Domain\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class CsvRowValidator
{
    private ValidatorInterface $validator;

    public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function isValid(CsvRowDto $dtoRow): ConstraintViolationList
    {
        return $this->validator->validate($dtoRow);
    }    
}
```

And the **csvRowDto.php**:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace whatever\Domain\Dto;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class csvRowDto
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     */
    private $rowId;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     */
    private $productNumber;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     */
    private $productName;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     */
    private $orderNumber;

    /**
     * @Assert\DateTime
     */
    private $orderDate;

    /**
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     */
    private $price;

    public function __construct(array $row)
    {
        $this->rowId = $row[0];
        $this->productNumber = $row[3];
        $this->productName = $row[4];
        $this->orderNumber = $row[5];
        $this->orderDate = $row[6];
        $this->price = $row[7];
    }

    public function toArray(): array
    {
        return [
            'row_id' => $this->rowId,
            'product_number' => $this->productNumber,
            'product_name' => $this->productName,
            'order_number' => $this->orderNumber,
            'order_date' => $this->orderDate,
            'price' => $this->price,
        ];
    }
}
```

How can I prevent the memory from running out while executing?

Comment: Have you tried using a [generator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php)?

Comment: Where have you placed that `memory_get_usage` call? You are still creating dto objects and the sample code doesn't give any indication as if you are flushing and freeing. It could very well be a memory limit issue. See the recommendations on [bulk insertion](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#bulk-inserts)

Comment: @msg Actually, this has nothing to do with Doctrine. I'm not using it while the insertion. I'm just trying to validate each row.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, after a while I found the answer in the **TraceableValidator** class itself.
So, in this class, it gathers all the validations in `collectedData` and accumulates it all in the same property:

```php
$this->collectedData[] = [
    'caller' => compact('name', 'file', 'line'),
    'context' => compact('value', 'constraints', 'groups'),
    'violations' => iterator_to_array($violations),
];
```

In the same `TraceableValidator` class, there is another function called `reset()`:

```php
public function reset()
{
    $this->collectedData = [];
}
```

So, I just needed to adjust the **CsvRowValidator.php**:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace whatever\Domain\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class CsvRowValidator
{
    private ValidatorInterface $validator;

    public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function isValid(CsvRowDto $dtoRow): ConstraintViolationList
    {
        $errors = $this->validator->validate($dtoRow);
        $this->validator->reset(); // <- This is the fix

        return $errors;
    }    
}
```

Comment: `TraceableValidator` only exists in the `dev` environment, as far as I know, so you might want to check the type before calling `reset`, as it's not part of `ValidatorInterface`.

Comment: Oh, that's a good approach to search for, but thanks for the hint and the support :)